# Paint method of Java (differencje environment b/w Win and Mac)

Tags: java, swing

```
package drop_the_bit_4;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class DropTheBeat extends JFrame {

    private Image screenImage;
    private Graphics screenGraphic;

    private ImageIcon exitButtonEnteredImage = new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("../images/exitButtonEntered.png"));
    private ImageIcon exitButtonBasicImage = new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("../images/exitButtonBasic.png"));

    private Image introBackground = new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("../images/introBackgroundTitle.jpg"))
        .getImage();
    private JLabel menuBar = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("../images/menuBar.png")));

    private JButton exitButton = new JButton(exitButtonBasicImage);

    private int mouseX, mouseY;

    public DropTheBeat() {
         setUndecorated(true);
        setTitle("Dynamic Beat");
        setSize(Main.SCREEN_WIDTH, Main.SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        setLayout(null);

        exitButton.setBounds(1245, 0, 30, 30);  
        exitButton.setBorderPainted(false);    
        exitButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);   
        exitButton.setFocusPainted(false);  
        [enter image description here][1]exitButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { 
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            exitButton.setIcon(exitButtonEnteredImage);
            exitButton.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
            Music buttonEnteredMusic = new Music("buttonEnteredMusic.mp3", false);
            buttonEnteredMusic.start();
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            exitButton.setIcon(exitButtonBasicImage);
            exitButton.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        }
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            Music buttonEnteredMusic = new Music("buttonPressedMusic.mp3", false);
            buttonEnteredMusic.start();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    add(exitButton);

    menuBar.setBounds(0, 0, 1280, 30);
    menuBar.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            mouseX = e.getX();
            mouseY = e.getY();
        }
    });
    menuBar.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            int x = e.getXOnScreen();
            int y = e.getYOnScreen();
            setLocation(x - mouseX, y - mouseY);
        }
    });
    add(menuBar);

    Music introMusic = new Music("introMusic.mp3", true);
    introMusic.start();
}


public void paint(Graphics g) {
    screenImage = createImage(Main.SCREEN_WIDTH, Main.SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    screenGraphic = screenImage.getGraphics();
    screenDraw(screenGraphic);
    g.drawImage(screenImage, 0, 0, null);
}

public void screenDraw(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(introBackground, 0, 0, null);
    paintComponents(g);
    this.repaint();
}
```

}

So this is the code.
Before I make the menubar with exit icons, my background image file appears correctly. But now, everything work except the background image. It appears black like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJqOU.png)

But when I work on windows, everything is ok. Is there any difference between MAC and Win about the paint method?

Comment: There are many issues with this code, including directly calling painting methods, calling `Thread.sleep` on the Swing event thread, using `setBounds`.... it looks like you're doing a lot of guessing and not much tutorial reading. Consider reversing that.

Comment: You can't just give us a dump of your code and expect the community to help you figure out why it doesn't work cross platform. I assume you have tried to figure it out yourself? Tell us what you've tried, and what your have found during research, what do you suspect might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
```

Don't override paint() on a JFrame. Custom painting is done by overriding paintComponent() on a JPanel and then you add the panel to the frame. Read the Section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples to get you started.

```
setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

Don't use transparent Colors for backgrounds. Swing doesn't paint them properly.

For full transparency in Swing you just use `setOpaque(false)` on the component

For partial transparency, see [Backgrounds With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for more information and a solution.

```
setLayout(null);
```

Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. The Swing tutorial also has a section on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).

Keep a link to the Swing tutorial handy for Swing basics.